# Computer restarts on Windows 7 start screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, reboot

I recently replaced my motherboard with an almost identical one that I bought off eBay (didn't change any other piece of hardware). The computer turns on fine. However, as soon as the Windows 7 start screen shows up, the computer restarts itself. I was thinking maybe this has something to do with the CPU overheating or something. What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: If the system is confused, like a bad shutdown in the past, you might try doing a safe mode boot up.   Usually you can get that by hitting the F8 key at the right time during boot (in practice just keep hitting it over and over until you get a safe boot prompt).  But if it is a thermal problem, it will still fail though

Comment: in addition, motherboards oftenhave integrated peripherals these days.  It might be a driver issue due to the new motherboard needing new drivers

Comment: If you want to check the hardware out first, and worry about OS later, you might try getting boot media for a live filesystem version of Linux, like `Knoppix`, and try booting off that.   There is usually a copy of `memtest86` included, which may be nice to try on a new motherboard

Comment: Did you replace the thermal paste on the CPU/Fan? Does safe mode work?

Comment: @Burgi, yes I did replace the thermal paste.

Comment: Now, I'm thinking maybe it's because the copy is an OEM and doesn't recognize the motherboard.

Comment: did you reinstall the OS? or have you put a different motherboard on and are trying to boot the same os you had on the old one?  Define "almost identical" with the actual model numbers?   Did you setup the Bios very important settings first Like the AHCI stuff (which will crash)?

Comment: @Psycogeek No, I have not reinstalled anything. All I did was take out the dead motherboard and replace it with one that looks 100% identical. This is an HP PC and the part numbers are also identical (531966-001), but the "new" one has a different rev. I haven't set up the BIOS. You have a good point that there might be a problem with the AHCI settings. Do you have an idea how to go about changing the settings?

Comment: ? get into the bios?  you got to that startup screen, so getting into the bios should be possible hitting DEL or F2 Or F12 during post before boot, or find the manuel for the correct button.  Revision on the same board should not be the problem , it is only rarely that they would completly change something like an audio or disk chip in revisions.  Also agrees with infixed, safe modes might be a bit safer (less drivers and software) and it could be a heat or tuning issue .  Manufactured computers bios setups are often so limited and I have never dealt with them.

Comment: @Psycogeek OK, it was the AHCI setting. Had to change it to IDE. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please self-answer your own question with full steps you took to resolve the problem, to help others.  Also you might want to turn off Auto Restart in the advanced system settings should you get any other crashes then it is more likely to BSOD with visable error item.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the SATA mode from AHCI to IDE. Problem fixed.